# Custom Sender and Reply-to in MS Office email mail merge

Tags: mail-merge

I'm trying to set up a mail merge that will be sent on behalf of another account.  With a reply-to address set to be a completely different account in an exchange environment.

Everything I've read suggest that I can't do these without 3rd party tools.  My questions are:

- Is there a secret window in Word or Outlook that I'm missing?
- Does anyone have personal experience with any of the 3rd party apps that claim to have this functionality?  (Mail Merge Toolkit, etc.)

fwiw, I'm on office 2013 but it seems to have the same deficiencies as previous editions.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my workaround.  It's still a little manual, but for small merges like mine it's fairly effective.  The key is to get the merge to dump the output into the Outlook Outbox instead of sending right away and using Outlook to set the custom sender and reply addresses.

Here are the steps I used in Outlook 2010/2013.

1. Open Outlook and go to the File Menu->Options->Advanced
2. Scroll down to *Send and receive*
3. Uncheck *Send immediately when connected* and click OK
4. Go to Word and do your mail merge as normal
5. Now go back into Outlook and look in the *Outbox*
6. You can now open each message and manually tweak the from address and direct reply information
7. Make sure to save your changes or hit *Send* to save them
8. Go to the *Send / Receive* tab and click *Send All*

That should send every message in the Outbox, be sure to roll back your "Send immediately when connected" setting to resume normal email usage.